# Minimal degree affect on a tree subgraph.

Tags: graph-theory

Show that each graph G with minimal degree m contains any tree with m+1 vertices as a subgraph.
I have no idea how to start here, would appreciate help. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^. Is there anything you've tried? Or ideas you have, however vague? Once we have a better idea of where exactly you're struggling, we can help you better

Comment: Sure, I'm struggling on how to prove it. I gurss the way to go is negation, meaning Let G be a graph with minimal degree m, and there exists a tree with m+1 vertices that G does not contain as a subgraph... but I'm getting stuck here...

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Induct on $m$.

First, can you show the $m=1$ case is true?

Then, assume the claim for graphs of minimal degree $m$. We want to show the claim for a graph of minimal degree $m+1$.

Fix a graph $G$ with minimal degree at least $m+1$. Fix your favorite tree $T$ with $m+2$ vertices. Then remove a leaf $u$ from $T$ to get a tree $T'$ with $m+1$ vertices.

- Can you use the inductive hypothesis to show $G$ contains a copy of $T'$?
- Can you use the fact that $G$ has minimal degree $m+1$ to find a way to reattach $u$ to $T'$ in $G$? This will give you a copy of $T$ in $G$. As desired.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Thank you so much. Going over it now.

Comment: Shouldn't we start from m=0 zero here?
And then all the vertices are the subgraphs...

Comment: I'm afraid I did not understand yet. What do you mean by "fix your favorite tree T with m+2 vertices"? How can I know such tree exists?, and the rest is also kind of vague for me...

Comment: First -- you can start at $m=0$ if you want. The proof still goes through.  Second -- you want to show that $G$ contains every tree $T$. So for any $T$ you pick, you have to show it's in $G$. Third -- I left it vague, we're here to help guide you, not necessarily solve your problem directly. _Especially_ for something that sounds like a homework problem